# Reduction of order method for second order linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the following differential equation
>
> $$x^2 y'' + x(2x^2 + 1)y' + (2x^2 -1)y =0$$
>
> solve it using the reduction of order method.  The given solution is $$y_1(x) = \frac 1x.$$

I have been able to use it up until the point where you define your 2nd set of variables such that the expression is in terms of derivatives only:

$$\frac{u'}{x^2} + \frac{u''}{x} + 2u' = 0$$

Let $w = u'$ and $w' = u''$. Now when I try to solve for $w$, I get the following:

$$w + w'x + 2wx^2 = 0$$

$$\frac{w'}{w} = \frac{1+2x^2}{x}$$

and after integrating both sides

$$w = A\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}$$

Now I have to integrate again to get $u$ by itself, but I cannot solve the integral of $\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}$ using substitution or integrating by parts. I have tried using websites like Wolfram Alpha to no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually that method requires that one solution is already known? Was one solution given in the task description?

Comment: ah yes sorry, the given solution was $y= 1/x$

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to double check your work! The last equation should be $w=xe^{x^2},$ which is easy to integrate.

Comment: oh really? i cant see it yet but which part of my calculation was wrong?

Comment: When you integrate the 2nd to last equation you get $\ln w = \ln x + x^2 + C.$

Comment: ahhh i was just reviewing my work at came across this mistake, i should be able to complete the question now, many thanks!